# Microsoft Access Compile Error: Method or data member not found

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am creating a simple login form for my Database. When I click login, the message "Compile Error: Method or data member not found" appears. How do I fix that? Thanks! Code is below

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Sub btnLogin_Click()
    Dim rs As Recordset

    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("TBL:Staff", dbOpenSnapshot, dbReadOnly)

    rs.FindFirst "UserName='" & Me.txtUserName & "'"

    If rs.NoMatch = True Then
        Me.lblWrongUser.Visible = True
        Me.txtUserName.SetFocus
        Exit Sub
        Me.lblWrongUser.Visible = False

    If rs!Password <> Nz(Me.txtPassword, "") Then
        Me.lblWrongPass.Visible = True
        Me.txtPassword.SetFocus
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Me.lblWrongPass.Visible = False
    DoCmd.OpenForm "FRM:Customer"
    DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name
End Sub
```

Comment: Please provide the row giving the error.

Comment: Row 4 is causing the error

Comment: I think Erik means the line in the code.

Comment: Private Sub btnLogin_Click()

Comment: Besides, this won't compile as an `End If` is missing.

Comment: Where should the End If go?

Comment: Looking at the indentation, after the line `Me.lblWrongUser.Visible = False` And this line will never be executed  because an `Exit Sub` is right before it.

Comment: Before clicking on the "Login" button, first run the Compile command. if there is an error, the compiler should stop at the line with the error, indicating the item not found.

Comment: Please fix the question so the code is syntactically correct.

Comment: `end if` goes at the end of the `if/then` code block .  it is your decision where the block ends. ... when you ask where the _end if_ should go, it indicates that you need to learn what _if_ code blocks are used for

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

Check username and password values have been provided, then see if they exist in the database by a simple `DCount`.

If the username/password exist it will return > 0 and if not, it will return 0.

```
Private Sub btnLogin_Click()
    With Me
        'Username/Password - value provided?
        If IsNull(.txtUserName.Value) Or IsNull(.txtPassword.Value) Then
            MsgBox "Both fields required.", vbExclamation
            Exit Sub
        End If

        'Username exists in Table?
        If DCount("*", "Staff", "UserName='" & .txtUserName.Value & "'") = 0 Then
            .lblWrongUser.Visible = True
            .txtUserName.SetFocus
            Exit Sub
        End If

        'Password exists in Table?
        If DCount("*", "Staff", "UserName='" & .txtUserName.Value & _
                                "' And Password='" & .txtPassword.Value & "'") = 0 Then
            .lblWrongPass.Visible = True
            .txtPassword.SetFocus
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End With

    'Code will reach here only if supplied username and passowrd are correct
    With DoCmd
        .OpenForm "Customer", acNormal, , , acFormPropertySettings, acWindowNormal
        .Close acForm, Me.Name, acSavePrompt
    End With
End Sub
```